# textField input & auto calculated text in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I started Flutter recently because i need to make an IOS copy from already lunched App on android using Java... the aim is to make 3 `textFields` which allow the user from entering the text & at the same time it will do simple math calculation... for example if `textField1` & `textField2` entered the summation of 1 & 2 will be shown in `textField3`, the user can keep the value and use it or re-type it, the same should happen for `textField1`&`textField3`, the result will be displayed in `textField2`... so I tried several time to do so, but I have some issues that once summation is entered in `textField3` i can't change it...also i can't apply the first step to the second case..
[image]

can somebody help me please

```
class _TryPageState extends State<TryPage> {
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  var velocityEditingController = TextEditingController();
  var finalValue = TextEditingController();

  int airFlow;
  int velocity;
  int valueFinal;
  String sam, sam2;
  String airFlowText, velocityText, finalText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    finalValue.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }

  String totalCalculated() {
    airFlowText = textEditingController.text;
    velocityText = velocityEditingController.text;
    finalText = finalValue.text;

    if (airFlowText != '' && velocityText != '') {
      sam = (airFlow + velocity).toString();
      finalValue.value = finalValue.value.copyWith(
        text: sam.toString(),
      );
    }
    return sam;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            // key: Key(totalCalculated()),
            controller: textEditingController,
            onChanged: (textEditingController) {
              setState(() {
                airFlow = int.parse(textEditingController.toString());
              });
            },
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                textEditingController.clear();
              });
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter Value',
              labelText: 'Air Flow',
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: velocityEditingController,
            onChanged: (velocityEditingController) {
              setState(() {
                velocity = int.parse(velocityEditingController.toString());
              });
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter Value',
              labelText: 'Velocity',
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            key: Key(totalCalculated()),
            controller: finalValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                finalValue.value = finalValue.value.copyWith(
                  text: value.toString(),
                );
              });
            },
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                finalValue.clear();
                finalValue.value = finalValue.value.copyWith(
                  text: '',
                );
              });
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter Value',
              labelText: 'Final Value',
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          ),
          Text('Entered Value is  $airFlow + $velocity + ${finalValue.text}'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: so basically when you try to edit. the textfield gets cleared. but you want to keep text as it in un-edited textfield and change only when the user changes the input

Comment: after we do the simple calculation & the result appears in the textField, if the user want to edit the result box without affecting the textField 1 & 2 he can... & the new value of textField 3 (the entered one) will be used in another function.